# Append not working as expected in MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, append

I have two tables `test1` and `Table1` created in MS Access as shown below:

[image: test1]

[image: Table1]

I want to append all the data from `test1` to `Table1` but I do not know neither how to get the data from one table nor how to append it in the other table.
How should I proceed?

Comment: please specify how did you try . Show your code

Answer (score 0):

you could use a insert select

```
insert into table1 (name, class)
select name, class 
from test1
```